# Switching from instancecontextmode.Single to PerCall Loop through event problem

Tags: c#, wcf, instancecontextmode

I'm fairly new to using the WCF and trying to improve some old pieces of code (so forgive me if I'm asking some dumb questions).
I have a WCF in singleton mode and to improve my response time, I want to switch to a per-call mode. My only problem is that inside my constructor I subscribe to one event that manages all the messages flow inside my system.

```
_controllers.ForEach(c =>
        {
            c.OnTelegramSent += Controller_OnTelegramSent;
            c.OnTelegramReceived += Controller_OnTelegramReceived;
            c.OnPublicVariablesUpdated += Controller_OnPublicVariablesUpdated;
        });
```

So after that while, I'm trying to manage this event with my method I keep looping for the same message multiple times.

```
private void Controller_OnTelegramReceived(object sender, GenericEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Arguments[1].ToString().Contains("ACKT") && !e.Arguments[1].ToString().Contains("PING") && !e.Arguments[1].ToString().Contains("ASTA"))
        {
            ServicesMgr.Instance.NotifyTelegram(true, ((TrafficController)sender).Code, e.Arguments[1].ToString());

            Task.Run(() => SendNotifications((TrafficController)sender, e));
        }
    }
```

I don't even know if this is possible to use the per-call mode for this type of situation. One thing I noticed is that I subscribe multiple times to the same event and never unsubscribe, but I don't know how to manage that. I have the destructor where I unsubscribe from events but other than that I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The per-call pattern works well with dense resources such as connection objects and large memory objects. And scalability is a prime requirement. Depending on your situation, try per-session first.